# Adding a new view on top in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

Anyone got a tip how to add a View over the current view (modal)? I'm creating an app with a video recorder, and the video screen is presented modally on the screen. I want some text to show up above the video modal, and I think I've tried any approach I can think of atm.

Currently im stuck with something like:

```
var topMost = frameModule.topmost();
var View = new ViewModule.View(questionHolder);
topMost.currentPage._addView(View, 0);
```

But with no success. questionHolder is a view I fetch with

```
currentpage.getViewById
```

Edit:

From the answer of @davecoffin where I understood you could not mix native views and nativescripts views, I was able to solve this in my case by accessing the native view directly and adding a subview to it. In my case:

```
var sharedApplication = utils.ios.getter(UIApplication, UIApplication.sharedApplication);
    var overlay = UIView.alloc().initWithFrame({
        origin : {
            x: 0, 
            y: 44,
        },
        size: {
            height: 100,
            width: platform.screen.mainScreen.widthPixels
        }
    });
    overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor;
    overlay.alpha = .6;

    sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I am understanding your approach correctly...
You cant add Nativescript views on top of native views. 
Check out this forum question: https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/appending-nativescript-views-to-a-native-ui-view/1412

Basically once you have appended a native view (not a nativescript layout or ui view), then every view you append after that must be a native view. For iOS you use addSubview, not sure about android atm.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, actually got me in the right direction so that I was able to solve it (for my purpose)

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

You can directly create and use **modal pages** as described in [this article](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#modal-pages).